# updating variable in http request callback in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

This is probably easy but nevertheless. I have a http call in my controller where I load a json file. I want to update a variable in my html based on a result. It updates apparently the variable (console.log) in JS but not in the html.
Is there a way to use $apply with the result or similar? What else to use?
Here's a [(not) working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pIkAagKCdUUTprwiIaiM)

JS:

```
    function SomeController($http){
  this.someValue = 'initial';
  $http.get('test.json').then(function (data) {
    this.someValue="changed";
    console.log("get request "+this.someValue);
  });
}

app.controller('someController', SomeController);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="someController as some">
      <p>{{some.someValue}}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we create a function it has its own `this`(context). In your case `this` you're using inside `$http.get` success function is not `this`(context) of `SomeController` function. You have to keep the `SomeController` function context inside `self` variable & then use that variable in your success callback of `$http.get` function so that `this` will be treated as a global variable.

**Controller**

```
function SomeController($http){
  var self =this;
  self.someValue = 'initial';
  $http.get('test.json').then(function (data) {
    self.someValue="changed";
    console.log("get request "+this.someValue);
  });
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/P1D75KA5asqyQTKcktqj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your `controller` and in `$http` are different because they are in different block of scope so assign `this` in another variable like `_this` and use it.

Try it

```
function SomeController($http){
  var _this = this;
  _this.someValue = 'initial';
  $http.get('test.json').then(function (data) {
    _this.someValue="changed";
    console.log("get request "+_this.someValue);
  });
}
```